# Django channels error : TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

I am working on Django channels and Async application and I am totally new into it.
I started seeing tutorials for that . When I ran django server , it works fine but when I load the page or try to connect with websocket king client for testing the server , it show the error  ->

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/game/roomname [127.0.0.1:51190]
Exception inside application: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 263, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 185, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 150, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asgiref\compatibility.py", line 34, in new_application
    return await instance(receive, send)
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/game/roomname [127.0.0.1:51190]
```

I am new into it and I am unable to solve the problem . Kindly help .

My project asgi.py

```
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter , URLRouter 
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from home.consumers import GameRoom
from django.urls import path

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tictac.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()

ws_pattern = [
    path("ws/game/<room_code>" , GameRoom)
]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket" : AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(
        ws_pattern
    ))
})
```

If possible please provide a detailed explanation to this so that I understand what is the error .

Comment: What version of django and channels are you using? Try to use `GameRoom.as_asgi()`

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply , I tried adding .as_asgi() it gave me error that NoneType object has not attribute "group_add" and i am using django_channels of version3.0.4

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback for the new error? You seem to have missing/misconfigured [`CHANNEL_LAYERS`](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html)

Comment: Try to use channels==3.0.4

Comment: The problem is solved buddy . I have used .as_asgi() function after the consumer name . It worked .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your

```
ws_pattern = [
    path("ws/game/<room_code>" , GameRoom)
]
```

With

```
ws_pattern = [
    path("ws/game/<room_code>" , GameRoom.as_asgi())
]
```